# Transactional ALTER statements in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rollback, transactional

I'm doing an update to MySQL Database which includes MySQL scripts that make ALTER TABLE sentences, as well as DIU sentences (delete, insert, update).

The idea is to make a transactional update, so if a sentence fails, a rollback is made, but if I put ALTER TABLE sentences or others specified in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/implicit-commit.html an implicit commit is made, so I can't make a complete rollback, because the indicated operations remains commited.

I tried to use mysqldump to make a backup which is used in case of error (mysql returns distinct to zero), but it is too slow and can fail too.

What can I do? I need this to ensure that future updates are safe and not too slow, because databases contains between 30-100 GB of data.

Comment: alter is always going to be slow in big databases - it makes a copy of the table. either you make a copy by dumping, or you make a copy with alter, but a copy will be made.

Comment: Only DML is transactional. That's it, no solutions

Comment: How can I "make a copy and restore to it in case of failure" in a MySQL script? (To make all-in-one-step calling that script)

Comment: Check article I posted in my answer. It has all in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dump and reload might be your best options instead of `alter table`.

From mysql prompt or from the database script:

`select * from mydb.myt INTO OUTFILE '/var/lib/mysql/mydb.myt.out';

drop table mydb.myt;

create table`myt`(your table ddl here)

load data infile '/var/lib/mysql/mydb.myt.out' INTO TABLE mydb.myt;`

Check this out:

http://everythingmysql.ning.com/profiles/blogs/whats-faster-than-alter

I think it offers good guidance on "alternatives to alter".

Answer (score 0):

Look at pt-online-schema change.

You can configure it to leave the 'old' table around after the online ALTER is completed.  The old table will have an underscore prefix.  If bad things happen, drop the tables you altered and renamed the OLD tables to the original tables.  If everything is OK, then just drop the OLD tables.

http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-online-schema-change.html